# Can GNU Parallel be made to output the command line executed when run in linewise mode?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Suppose I have a list of commands in file `cmd_file`.

I run these commands via:

```
cat cmd_file | parallel -k -I {} "{}"
```

One of the commands fails.  All of the commands use the exact same CLI tool with different inputs.

Right now, I have to run across all of the commands one at a time to find the erroring command by substituting my command list for a command builder loop (much more involved):

```
for ...; do
  # assemble the vars for the command
  echo "<command>"
  <command>
done
```

Is there a mechanic for getting parallel to display the command that failed, or the execution order onto stderr, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instruct [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) to print each command executed either to standard output or to standard error.  From the `man` page:

```
-v  Print the job to be run on stdout (standard output).
    Can be reversed with --silent. See also -t.


-t  Print the job to be run on stderr (standard error).
```

So perhaps:

```
for ...; do
  # assemble the vars for the command
  echo "<command>"
done |
parallel -v -k
```

or if you have `cmd_file` already prepared:

```
parallel -v -k < cmd_file
```

or something similar will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If the command sets the exit value, `--joblog` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a mechanic for getting parallel to display the command that failed, or the execution order onto stderr, for example?

GNU Parallel 20220722 has `--colour-failed`:

```
parallel --tag --colour-failed "echo foo {}; {}" ::: true true false false true
```

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks Ole